# Hide tabbar when camera is open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uitabbarcontroller

Everyone I am working on a tabbar-based app. I open camera on a screen in order to picture. But when camera is open, i cant see the Take photo button on the bottom. My guess is that the button gets hidden behind the tab bar. If I am right then I need to remove tab bar on the camera screen. Can anyone please tell me how I can remove the tab bar on the camera screen?

I am using this to display the camera:

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

My app is tabbar-based and this code is written in a view controller which is associated with a tab bar item.

```
if (!imagePickerController) {
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;

// If our device has a camera, we want to take a picture, otherwise, we just pick from
// photo library
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}else
{
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Your device does not support taking photos from camera. Redirecting you to Photos Library instead." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

// image picker needs a delegate so we can respond to its messages
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
}
// Place image picker on the screen
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: There should be no tab bar there. This is a modal viewcontroller, and a takephotobutton should be there ... hm.

Comment: HI Legolas thanks for the reply. I have iPhone 4G. When i run the app on it, I see the tabbar on the bottom and the camera remains open. On top of the camera view I can see Flash and switch camera buttons. Tab bar is there and i dont want it on the camera screen. please help!

Comment: From my experience the tab cannot show up. please post your complete code.

Comment: Legolas, I posted my code as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Present the image-picker controller from the tab-bar controller instead of the view controller it contains. In other words:

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I tried but nothing happens. Image picker controller does not show up.

Comment: Hmm. Is your view controller inside a navigation controller? You might have to use `self.navigationController.tabBarController` instead.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please choose the category you want your picture to be uploaded in." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"General" otherButtonTitles:@"Fresh Cuts", nil];
    [alert show];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)   //general
    {
        selected_category = 0;
    }
    else                    // fresh cuts
    {
        selected_category = 1;
    }
}


-(IBAction) uploadFromCameraButtonPressed{
    if (!imagePickerController) {
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;

        // If our device has a camera, we want to take a picture, otherwise, we just pick from
        // photo library
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        }else
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Your device does not support taking photos from camera. Redirecting you to Photos Library instead." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        // image picker needs a delegate so we can respond to its messages
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user_email"];

    NSMutableString *imageName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];

    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    if (theUUID) {
        [imageName appendString:NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID))];
        CFRelease(theUUID);
    }
    [imageName appendString:@".png"];

    StatusBO *statusObj = [PhotoBO uploadImageFile:userName imageData:imageData file_name:imageName c_id:self.selected_category];

    if(statusObj.errorOccured == YES){
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:statusObj.errorTitle message:statusObj.errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }else{
    //  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:statusObj.errorTitle message:statusObj.errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        //[alertView show];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}


-(IBAction) uploadFromFileButtonPressed{
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(IBAction) backButtonPressed{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(IBAction) takePhotoFromCamra{

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set frame size to full for  modal view so that it covers up the whole screen - Dimensions ~ `(0,0,320,460)`

```
imagePicker.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,320,460);
```

Comment: i guess its something to do with tabbar controller. Actually I have a view controller which opens when I select a tabbar item. Now on this view controller's view, I add another viewcontroller's view as a subview. The code which I sent to you is from that second viewcontroller. Can this be the problem?

Comment: No it will still not be a problem. The whole point of modal view controllers is that it should be completely visible to the user. It is on top of all views.

Comment: I fixed it by writing [appDelegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES]; where appDelegate is the instance of my Delegate class. Am I correct? By the way code works.

Comment: ha ha. Yes. Why not. That should definitely solve the problem.